# Putting component assets inside its own directory

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular5

I'm using Angular 6.

I know how to access images in the following way:

```
http://localhost.com:4200/assets/image.png
```

by putting that image on the path:

```
/src/assets/image1.png
```

but right now I'm doing a component which is on the path:

```
/src/app/components/mycomp
```

then I want to use another `image2.png` which is gonna be used only by this component. Then I don't want to put this image on a global directory like on the first case. Instead, I want to put that image on this location:

```
/src/app/components/mycomp/assets/image2.png
```

The goal is to make this component easily portable.

Also, on the file: `mycomp.component.css` I'm gonna reference that file.

Is anyway to do this?

On this project I will have many of individual components, each of them with multiple different assets and I don't want to mix all these assets. I want each component has his own space/directory.

Is anyway to achieve this?

Comment: The easiest way would just be to put them in subdirectories within `assets`, so `src/assets/mycomp/image2.png` for example

Comment: but if I use: `src/assets/mycomp/image2.png` then I'm not wrapping the component assets on its own directory and that will break the portability of this component. Any other idea?

Comment: In the case, for each directory that contains static assets, you'll need to add them into angular.json (or angular-cli.json depending on your version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve your task by encoding your images using base64 converter (for example https://www.base64-image.de/). 
If your images can be converted to SVG - you can also embed them into your templates.
Hope this will help you.